# Can I connect my Mini DisplayPort monitor with a Thunderbolt cable?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

I wanted to go to the Apple Store and pick up a Thunderbolt cable, as they seem to be the only store in the area that has a Mini DisplayPort (style) in the Thunderbolt cable. My monitor requires mini display port to broadcast at 60Hz at 4k resolution.

Will the Thunderbolt cable work in lieu of a Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible!

But all you need is a Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable. Skip this upscale Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt cable. You'll find Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cables much cheaper in other retailers.

For example [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=mini%20display%20port%20cable)..